# Node class Java optional Parameters

Tags: java, node.js

I'm pretty new to Java and wondering how would I make a Node class. This is what I got

Node.java (Interface)

```
public interface Node {



  /**
   * get the nodes id.
   * @return the id of the node.
   */
  public int getId();

  /**
   * Checks if nodes have same id.
   * @param n the node to be compared to.
   * @return true if nodes have same id, false otherwise.
   */
  public boolean equals(Node n);
}
```

NodeImpl.java (implementation)

```
public class Nodelmpl implements Node {

  private int data;
  private Node next;

  public Nodelmpl(int data, Node next) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
  }

  @Override
  public int getId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Node n) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.data == n.getId();
  }

}
```

I believe the next isn't optional?

In Python I could write

```
a = Node(1, Node(2, Node(3)))
```

To get a basic linked list of a: 1->2->3->None How would I write this in Java?

Comment: `Node a = new NodeImpl(1, new NodeImpl(2, new NodeImpl(3, null)));`

Comment: Either use `null` as the `next` parameter, or make the `next` optional by adding another `Nodelmpl` constructor that only has a `data` parameter (this is called overloading, which you can't do in Python).  Please also note that you probably want your class name to be `NodeImpl` with an upper-case `I`, but you've made the letter after "e" a lower-case `L`.  Unfortunately they look exactly the same in some fonts.